# AWS S3 StringLike Condition preventing requests to bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have the following s3 IAM policy. It is intended to allow me to copy files from or put files into a bucket below from location temp/prod/tests within the bucket.

In the policy, I have added the StringLike condition, which I had hoped would allow the permissions in the policy to allow copying and puts when the object prefix contains `temp/prod/tests`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/temp/prod/tests/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "temp/prod/tests/*",
                        "temp/prod/tests/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that the condition prevents me from copying anything under temp/prod/tests/, or putting any new object in this bucket beneath this location.

```
 $ aws s3 cp --recursive s3://MYBUCKET/temp/prod/tests/ /tmp
download failed: s3://MYBUCKET/temp/prod/tests/testfiles/testfile to ../../../tmp/testfiles/testfile An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

And

```
$ aws s3 cp /tmp/test s3://MYBUCKET/temp/prod/tests/
 An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

If I remove the Condition, I am able to copy the files as expected.

I don't understand why the condition is not working, because as far as I can see, the requests I am making match the prefix of the condition.

Does anyone know why this is not working as I expect?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the policy is derived from this blog post [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Following policy does as you mentioned in the question

> It is intended to allow me to copy files from or put files into a bucket below from location temp/prod/tests within the bucket

PLUS all the actions within the folder `temp/prod/tests/*`. Those can be restricted further. Like you have few permissions asigned.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::: MYBUCKET"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "temp/prod/tests/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::: MYBUCKET/temp/prod/tests/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the confusion here is your expectation that `s3:prefix` will be present and testable during a CopyObject request. It's present during a ListBucket request, but not a CopyObject request.

Based upon the following statement from [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-condition-keys.html#s3-specific-keys), you can only create a condition on a specific key if that key is present as a request header on the corresponding S3 API call:

> You can use Amazon S3 condition keys with specific Amazon S3 actions. Each condition key maps to the same name request header allowed by the API on which the condition can be set

Specifically, I believe that `s3:prefix` will be absent during an actual [CopyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) request and that means that IAM will treat this as [values do not match](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html), hence the conditional test fails and the CopyObject request is denied.

In the case of your policy, I'd suggest:

- use bucket resources with bucket actions and object resources with object actions (right now, you are mixing them together)
- limit your prefix conditions to the ListBucket operation
- no need to make GetObject or PutObject conditional, simply indicate the resource ARN for which these operations will be allowed (e.g. `arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/temp/prod/tests/*`)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think it is a good practice to split the rules according to resources. Some of the s3 actions require a bucket, some of them require an object. It's in the documentation to every service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html

Furthermore, the conditions instead of proper resources make the policy even more confusing.

In theory, for uploading an object you need just PutObject, you don't even need any List action. But for various cmdline tools I am curious about how far you would get with something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "rule1",
            "Effect": "Allow",            
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/temp/prod/tests/*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "rule2",
            "Effect": "Allow",            
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET",
            ]
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I assign this rule to IAM role? If I need specific Bucket Policy

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works with minimal change to the policy.
I added ForAllValues to the condition, and now I can copy any objects beneath temp/prod/tests/ or any of the subdirectories below temp/prod/tests/.

```
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "temp/prod/tests/*",
                    "temp/prod/tests/"
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ideally, you should be more concerned with writing a 100% correct and valid policy than minimizing the number of changes you make to an invalid policy.