# I don't understand why this IAM policy using a StringLike condition for an S3 bucket doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket named `my.example.com`, and within it I have the folder `Folder1`.

I'm confused about why the following policy doesn't let me download files from `Folder1`.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "MyPolicy",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:Get*",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.example.com",
         "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
               "s3:prefix": [
                  "Folder1/*"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

However, this policy does let me download files

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "MyPolicy",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:Get*",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.example.com/Folder1/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Why doesn't the first policy work?

Comment: But aren't the objects that I'm trying to get prefixed with `Folder1/`?

Comment: @luk2302 I tried changing it to `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.example.com/*"`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878496/271415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resource:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.example.com",
```

is for the **bucket only**, not for any objects in the bucket. Thus, for your policy to apply to the objects it should be:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.example.com/*",
```

`s3:prefix` is **not supported** for `s3:GetObject` actions as shown in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys). So that's why it does not work for you.

Instead your resource should be

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.example.com/Folder1/*",
```

Comment: If I change the `Resource` to what you suggested and remove the `Condition`, it works.  But with the `Condition`, it doesn't work.  Do you know why that is?